# Инициализация динамического массива символов строкой C-style в C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему, начиная с C++11, мы не можем инициализировать динамический массив символов строкой C-style?

```
    char *array = new char[15] { "What the hell?" }; // не работает в C++11
```

В чём причина запрета?
Вместо этого приходится динамически выделять std::string (или выделять динамический массив символов, а затем с помощью функции strcpy_s() скопировать содержимое нужной строки в этот массив).

Comment: В [icc](https://godbolt.org/z/9xTh4ods7), [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/nnsrs6MrT), [clang](https://rextester.com/EKRK86442), а также [новых версиях gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cce16551cc70dc8f) приведённый код работает. Либо баг в компиляторе, который исправили в поздних версиях, либо баг в стандарте, который исправили в новых версиях стандарта.

Comment: "не работает" не является описанием проблемы

Comment: Ну сделайте [так](https://ideone.com/B1tcLr): `char *array = new char[15] { 'W','h','a','t',' ','t','h','e',' ','h','e','l','l','?','\0' };` В принципе, причина понятна: тип — массив `char`, а инициализатор — `const char*` — видимо, забыли исключение добавить и сюда :) Но VC++ нормально обрабатывает...

Comment: Кстати, VC++ забавно строку инициализирует — переносит 8 байт через  `xmm0`, затем через `eax` последовательно 4, 2 и 1 байт... Стоит сделать 16 байт — и все, один раз через `xmm0`...